# SQL HAVING Clause not returning what I expect

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, having

I am having a problem with a SQL query. The query in question looks like this:

```
SELECT TOP 3 r2.fdtmFilingPeriod 
FROM  TBLRETURN r2
WHERE r2.fstrDocType       = 'RT3001' 
AND   r2.FLNGVER           = 0 
AND   r2.fstrStatus        in ('RCVD', 'SUS') 
--AND r2.flngAccountKey    = 669 --has one row in the table     -- should return 0 rows
AND   r2.FLNGACCOUNTKEY    = 265   --has several rows the table -- should return 3 rows
GROUP BY r2.fdtmFilingPeriod
--HAVING COUNT(r2.fdtmFilingPeriod) > 2
ORDER BY    r2.FDTMFILINGPERIOD DESC;
```

The strange thing here is that when I uncomment the HAVING clause, I am not quite getting what seems to be in the database. What I get when i run the above query is this:

```
2013-12-31 00:00:00.000
2013-09-30 00:00:00.000
2013-06-30 00:00:00.000
```

This is clearly more than two rows, yet when I uncomment the HAVING clause I get no rows back. Can someone please help me to figure out what is going on here?

I am using SQL Server 2008.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Neither of those dates have a count greater than two rows?  12-31 has a count of 1 and 9-30 has a count of 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`HAVING` is like a `WHERE` clause, but on aggregate data for the grouping AFTER the grouping has been done.

You have:

```
HAVING COUNT(r2.fdtmFilingPeriod) > 2
```

First, `COUNT(r2.fdtmFilingPeriod)` just means counting not-null fields within the grouping you specified. So on a per `fdtmFilingPeriod` basis, what's the `COUNT`?

Of these rows you mention, the counts are:

```
2013-12-31 00:00:00.000    1
2013-09-30 00:00:00.000    2
```

Neither of these rows would pass your `HAVING` clause.

Also, to more easily see what the `HAVING` is making its decision on, just change the query to add the `COUNT` you are filtering on:

```
SELECT TOP 3 r2.fdtmFilingPeriod, COUNT(r2.fdtmFilingPeriod) AS CNT
FROM  TBLRETURN r2
WHERE r2.fstrDocType       = 'RT3001' 
AND   r2.FLNGVER           = 0 
AND   r2.fstrStatus        in ('RCVD', 'SUS') 
--AND r2.flngAccountKey    = 669 --has one row in the table     -- should return 0 rows
AND   r2.FLNGACCOUNTKEY    = 265   --has several rows the table -- should return 3 rows
GROUP BY r2.fdtmFilingPeriod
--HAVING COUNT(r2.fdtmFilingPeriod) > 2
ORDER BY    r2.FDTMFILINGPERIOD DESC;
```

Comment: Ok, thank you both. This makes the entire problem a good bit clearer to me.